# find sequence in the hashmap

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, sequence

I have a hashmap which represents [from, to]:

```
1st: [start->sb1]
2nd: [sb0->sb3]
3rd: [sb1->sb0]
4th: [sb3->end]
```

I would like if there is a way to find the correct sequence such as:

```
start->sb1->sb0->sb3->end
```

Comment: Sure, there's a way. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple recursion can do the trick:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Map<String, String> path = new HashMap<>();
    path.put("start", "sb1");
    path.put("sb0", "sb3");
    path.put("sb1", "sb0");
    path.put("sb3", "end");

    printPath(path, "start");
}

void printPath(Map<String, String> path, String next) {
    if (next != null) {
        System.out.print(next);
        printPath(path, path.get(next));
    }
}
```

This impl simply prints all entries on `System.out`. I assume that you would rather collect them in a `List` or similar if they are to be used later in the program.

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
buildPath(path, "start", result);

void buildPath(Map<String, String> path, String token, List<String> result) {
    if (token != null) {
        result.add(token);
        buildPath(path, path.get(token), result);
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to adapt your example with a com.google.common.collect.Multimap?

Answer (score 4):

If you know the `start` key, it's quite simple :

```
String key = "start";
while (key != null && !key.equals("end")) {
    System.out.print(key + "->");
    key = map.get(key);
}
if (key != null)
    System.out.println(key);
```

This assumes the key and value of the map are Strings.